# Disappearing DIVs on runtime?

Tags: css, html

In DreamWeaver everything is compiled okay and looks normal on the design tab, but when I switch over to localhost my contented DIVs only show text on the left side, when they should be in the middle.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">       
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="images/barColor.jpg" width="1" height="71" alt="barColor" />

    <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>   

    <div class="wrdLatest" id=1> content of id 1   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>              </div>                                                                     
<div class="wrdLatest" id=2> content of id 2   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=3> content of id 3   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>              </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=4> content of id 4   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=5> content of id 5   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=6> content of id 6   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=7> content of id 7   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=8> content of id 8   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=9> content of id 9   <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=10> content of id 10 <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=11> content of id 11 <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>
<div class="wrdLatest" id=12> content of id 12 <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p> </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

And then the style.css

```
  #wrdLatest {
        background: url('../images/spacing.png') repeat-y;
        z-index: -1;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-top: auto;
        width: 75%;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 25px;
        min-width: 25px;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        style="text-align: center;"
    }
```

1[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgsQb.png)
1[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62dxk.png)

Any help is much appreciated... and yes, I am new to HTML.

Comment: In "What I am getting" you have text that is not in the HTML code that you have posted???

Comment: Yea - It's just text , I changed all of it right before I took the picture, but still just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your code, you didn't close all of your divs with a closing tag `</div>` and also in your css `style="text-align: center;"` is not right, close all divs like

```
<div>Content</div>
```

and remove the line `style="text-align: center;"` from `#wrdLatest` or it should be

```
text-align: center;
```

`wrdLatest` is class in your HTML but you've used ID `#` in your css. A class should be as follows

```
.wrdLatest{
    background: url('../images/spacing.png') repeat-y;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the style="text-align: center;" but as for the /divs it got horribly mixed up with whitespacing, to me it seems that all the divs are closed, could you please specify?

Comment: Sorry, it's closed but looks horrible !

Comment: Absolutely horrible, I was just trying too many crazy things at the time trying to get this to work..

Comment: Just edited your code now, divs look closed now, it was already though.

Comment: Hmm...so why does this show up like this on DW? And is there any possible work around to get the image to repeat-y and yet still have text over it?

Comment: Inside the div `<p>` tags takes place, `<p>` tags are basically not inline, instead box model element. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/xDbjS/1/

Comment: Notice the first two divs without p.

Comment: So what you did was just outline the spaces...right? But does that interfere with the div other than space it out?

Comment: Awesome thanks so much, I beginning to understand <p> tags and classes now!

Answer (score 0):

Have modified the CSS to achieve a layout something like you wanted. Look at this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/8pG5s/3/).

Have used a border-left to show the left orange border. And also you have to use `.wrdLatest` instead of `#wrdLatest` for `div class`

The modifed version of the CSS...

```
.wrdLatest {
    background: url('../images/spacing.png') repeat-y;
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 5px 20px 70px 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 2px solid #FE642E;
}
```

And have removed all the extra empty `<p>`'s.

Hope this helps.